# how to get nested object

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got a problem with typescript/javascript code in my  angular app. I use a resolver to get data, for ex:

In my resolver service:

```
data: any = {};
getJson(/apiurl/).subsribe(x=>this.data.cars = x);
getJson(/apiurl/).subsribe(x=>this.data.bikes = x);
return this.data;
```

then in a component in ngOnInit I want to pass this retrived data to particural function:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.route.data.subscribe(data => this.onRetrivedCars(data["data['cars']"]));
this.route.data.subscribe(data => this.onRetrivedBikes(data["data['bikes']"]));
}
```

I really do not know how to get the cars object or the bikes object. I still receiving an undefined. 
The question is, how to properly get/access the data from the object, I tried many variants. I'd like to pass a particular piece of data straight to a function.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Read and pass the value like this: `(data => this.onRetrivedCars(data.cars)`. You should consider checking if the value retrieved from the server matches your model to avoid crashing on unsuccessful requests.

Comment: If the solution I suggested doesn't help, try examining the data object from `this.route.data.subscribe` in the browser's console: `console.log(data)`. Then you will be able to see its structure, maybe the object you look for is wrapped.